# Spring Data Flow Kubernetes JDBC Drivers

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to deploy an `jdbc-sink` to a Helm based Kuberentes install of Spring Cloud Data Flow.

How would I go about adding JDBC jars in order to make use of the starters? I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy the app (in this case MySQL):

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
 Description:
 Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:
     Property: driverclassname
    Value: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
    Reason: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
```

Would I need to extend the existing starter, and manually add the Driver as there's no way of guaranteeing which driver it should be using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ship the OSS license-friendly drivers for few databases in SCDF and the app-starters that require database access, including the `jdbc` applications.

For proprietary drivers, there's a procedure to patch the out-of-the-box app-starters that we maintain and ship — more details in the reference guide [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Einstein.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_patching_pre_built_applications).

Once when you bundle the relevant driver in the classpath, you'd produce a docker image to then use it in SCDF.

Comment: Where can I find a guide to produce a docker image of the new component created with new JDBC driver ?